# How to sort an list of references?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of linkedlist's node. Basically references to node objects. Some of the references point to the same object. Now my question is on how to sort them.

Input :

`List< node1, node3, node 4, node1, node2, node3>`

Output:

`List <node1, node1, node2, node3, node3, node4>`

Order could be arbitraty ie 
`List <node3, node3, node2, node4, node1, node1>`, but atleast the adjacent nodes should be next to each other.

Also note, the sorting is not based on 'node value' but simply based on node references.

MORE REFERENCE:

I have a map, `Map <headNode, tailNode>`. Since the linkedlist can intersect the map contains unique heads but does not contain unique tails. My intention is to sort the map based on 'value' and then walk through map with logic similar to if (tail at pos i != tail @ pos i + 1) then the 2 linkedlist done intersect and print them.

Comment: Post the code you have for a node! How are they referenced?

Comment: do you want to ensure the references in the list are unique, or the objects being referenced are unique. there is a difference.

Comment: provided more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort based on the [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) value of each element in the list. You can implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as follows:

```
enum IdentitySort implements Comparator<Node> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
        return Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(n1),
                               System.identityHashCode(n2));
    }
}
```

Then, you can use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Collections.sort(list, IdentitySort.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: System.identityHashCode can have collisions (necessarily, since we're squeezing a 64-bit address space down into a 32-bit hash), so sorting by it could lead to `(node1, node2, node1)`, if `node1` and `node2` happen to hash to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are plan to **eliminate the duplicates**, why don't you use `HashSet`

Comment: hashset will make sure the entries are unique, but not that the object pointed to by those references are unique. You can have multiple unique references point to the same object where equals() would return true.

Comment: This will not work if `equals()` is overridden to compare based on something other than reference.